# PHP Session variable changing

Tags: php, session

I'm working with a strange issue in php, i will put a simplified script.

I want to generate a rand string for each access on each access to index, and check at the beginning of the index if it's same on previous. The problem is that the value that i setup at the end of the file is not the one that i get in the beginning, the values are different!!

This never happens to me can anyone give me a clue of What could be happening? I have and .htaccess that always redirect any request to index.php, but i suppose that have nothing to do with this problem. I've checked that the Session ID is the same, but i can't understand why this is happening.

My index only have this:

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "<p><hr /></p>";
echo "IN SESSION:<br />".$_SESSION['formToken'];
echo "<p><hr /></p>";

echo ".......";

//Secure Form Tokens
unset($_SESSION['formToken']);
$_SESSION['formToken'] = rand();
echo "<p><hr /></p>";
echo "END SESSION:<br />".$_SESSION['formToken'];
```

The output first output is:

> rkvuu0ohghdsl32otkj5o28qt4
>
> IN SESSION: 1242741993   ...
>
> END SESSION: 562913922

If i Refresh the page the second output should be the IN SESSION the old value set in END SESSION but it' not, it's a completely different one!!!

> rkvuu0ohghdsl32otkj5o28qt4
>
> IN SESSION: 188673004 (IT SHOULD BE THE PREVIOUS END SESSION
> 562913922)   ...
>
> END SESSION: 525826707

Comment: if everything is routed through index.php then things like calls to favicons will cause it to change, you mention your checking if the value is the same that would involve at least one if statement, I only see `$_SESSION['formToken'] = rand();` which has no checks before it. Also on the first time around your get undefined index as it's not defined yet, so you should also enable error reporting

Comment: Iv'e hidden all code between, I'm just need to know why the value that i set ath the end of the file is not the one at the begining after a refresh

Comment: check server access log

Comment: in the access log i see:


82.154.124.88 - - [08/Jan/2021:10:28:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 340

82.154.124.88 - - [08/Jan/2021:10:28:22 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 338


WHat does it means

Comment: _“always redirect any request to index.php, but i suppose that have nothing to do with this problem”_ - yes it does, if actually more than the one single request you imagined to happen, happens. As @LawrenceCherone said, the favicon would be a prime candidate for this - even if you don’t have _any_ external resources specified in your HTML output, browsers will make a request for `/favicon.ico` by default, and if you redirect that request to your index.php as well … well then a new random value will be put into the session at that point.

Comment: So, use your browser dev tools to verify whether actually just one single request gets made, when you load the index.php - or whether there’s more, such as for the favicon. If the latter, then you will have to either disable your redirect of “everything” to the index.php, if you want this to work as intended - or inside the index.php, you have to check whether it was actually the index.php that was requested by the client in the first place, and only generate a new random value in the session in that particular case.

Comment: The problem was the favicon ... this was the first time the designer didn't provided a favicon, and i didn't added it to the header of the view .

Thanks very much  both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are approaching a CSRF Concept. If you are already using HTTPS you are not in need to change CSRF each request. This will destroy the user experience if he's using multiple tabs. Instead generate one CSRF per Session and/or per unique form.

```
.htaccess that always redirect any request to index.php,
```

In fact, this can be an issue. The browser i.e. requests favicon.ico per default. if every request is redirected to index.php, this will generate a new token.

Consider looking in your browser developer console and check your network tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that favicon file didn't exists and the server was redirecting twice to index.php (directive on .htaccess), if the file exists it wouldn't redirect .

So i've added a favicon.ico on my project and worked.

Thank @Lawrence Cherone and @CBroe